# Neo4j modeling relationship query

Tags: neo4j

I have a query regarding modeling a relationship in Neo4j:

Here is a graph that I am creating:

[image]

- Company1 has products - A, B, C
- Company2 has products - A, B, D
- Company2 competes with Company1

If I wanted to specify which products company2 is competing with company1 e.g. just product A. Would I have to put a list of products on the COMPETES relationship? or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the definition of 'competing' should be more explicit. From the diagram you post, my common sense is that they compete on A and B, because they are both offering these products.

Putting an array of product(ids) on the COMPETES rel could work, but is not very 'graphy'

I would add (:Competition) nodes, and link them to each of the competing companies, as well as to specific products. The advantage would be that you can use this node, or the rel to store data on the type of competition (price, quality).

[image: Graph model]

Another approach (perhaps even better) would be to create :(:Offering) nodes between the company and the products, and create [:COMPETES] rels between the competing offerings.

[image: Graph model 2]

Comment: Thanks Graphileon, the array of products ids was bothering me. I quite like option 1 as when we add company locations, I can add the location relationship to the competition node. The only thing I wanted to check is when a company instance should be created. Is it only between 2 companies (this allows me to add multiple products). What happens if a third company offers the same products? Create another competitor instance between company 3 and company x or something else?

Comment: @Swordfish I assume that you mean : "when a :Competition instance should be created". The first option requires that there is such a node between any two :Company nodes that compete.  So when adding a Company, you would create quite a  lot of nodes. This is also the reason why I personally prefer the second model, because you do only use [:COMPETES] rels when needed.

Comment: Yes sorry that's what I meant. In the second model, if I wanted to add competes for locations as well, I would have then have to also add offering nodes between companies and locations and then use COMPETES between them correct?

Comment: Yes. Your model needs to correspond to the granularity of the data and/or the slicing that you want to do.

Comment: Got it, thanks for all your advice.